# Returning Arrays from Methods

Tags: arrays, netbeans, methods, return

So I have to display the marks that are below average, and all the marks that are above average.

I don't know where to go with this next but here's what I have so far:

```
public static void main (String[]args) {
    int[]marks={50,60,30,90,70,40,80,44};
    int average=average(marks);
    int[]resultBelowAverage=getBelowAverage(marks,average);
    printIntArray(resultBelowAverage);
    int[]resultAverageandAbove=getAverageandAbove(marks,average);
    printIntArray(resultAverageandAbove);
}
```

This next method is used to calculate the average. I got the right answer for this one which is 58.

```
public static int average(int[] marks) {
    int i=0;
    int total=0;
    for(i=0;i<marks.length;i++){
        total=total+marks[i];
    }
    int average=total/i;
    return average;
}
```

This next method gets how many values in the array are below average.

```
public static int countBelowAverage (int[] numbers,int av){
    int size=0;
    for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++) {
        if (numbers[i]<av) {
            size=size+1; 
        }
    }

    return size;
}
```

This next method gets how many values in the array are above average.

```
public static int countAboveAverage (int[] numbers,int av) {
    int size=0;
    for(int i=0;i>=numbers.length;i++) {
        if (numbers[i]>=av) {
            size=size+1; 
        }   
    }

    return size;
}
```

This next method gets which values in the array are below average. I think this is where I went wrong.

```
public static int[] getBelowAverage(int[]numbers,int av) {
    int size=countBelowAverage(numbers,av);
    int[]belowAverage=new int[size];

    return belowAverage;
}
```

This next method gets which values in the array are above average.

```
public static int[] getAverageandAbove(int[] numbers,int av) {
    int size=countAboveAverage(numbers,av);
    int[]AboveAverage=new int[size];

    return AboveAverage;
}
```

This last method prints the arrays that are classified into below average and above average.

```
public static void printIntArray(int[]x) {
    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        System.out.println (x[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which methods are you having problems with?

Comment: Excuse me but why is this question downvoted? Ok maybe it's not asked very clearly but an author have made the effort to provide code and it seems she/he is really working on this. Let's not discourage people from asking.

Answer (score 0):

In your methods you just creating arrays of proper size, an empty arrays and returning them. You should put some marks that are below / above average to these arrays before returning

Like here:

```
int[]belowAverage=new int[size];
//you have an empty array just after creation with nothing inside
//enter here marks from the marks array that are below average
return belowAverage;
```

Exactly the same situation here:

```
int[]AboveAverage=new int[size];
//you have an empty array just after creation with nothing inside
//enter here marks from the marks array that are above average
return AboveAverage;
```

You may use an algorithm from peeskillet's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20033324/2948265) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to get the below average array

```
public static int[] getBelowAverage(int[]numbers,int av){
    int size=countBelowAverage(numbers,av);
    int[]belowAverage=new int[size];

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        if (numbers[i] < av){
            belowAverage[j] = numbers[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    return belowAverage;
}
```

Do similar for the above average method

Answer (score 0):

In your method getAverageandAbove you make an array, but you do not put anything in it.
you should loop through your numbers array again, and fill your AboveAverage array with the values that are greater than the average.